# Send function with hash

Tags: ruby, hash

I know my `x.to_s` is not working and I need to use `.send(something)` but I cannot get the syntax right. If you can show me the correct send syntax I'd appreciate it.

```
h = Hash.new 
@cars.each do|x| 
  h["x.to_s"] = 0 
end
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? If you are trying to use `x`'s string representation as a hash key, you must remove the quotation marks, i.e. `h[x.to_s] = 0`.

Comment: that fixed it, put in an answer and i'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean to use the string representation of `x` as a hash key, remove the quotation marks:

```
h[x.to_s] = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you find this:

```
h = Hash.new 
@cars.each do|x| 
  h[x.send(:to_s)] = 0
end
```

Comment: but I don't understand why your x.to_s doesn't work and x.send :to_s do... :S

Comment: No need to use `send`. `x.to_s` will suffice. The OP had quote around it i.e. `"x.to_s"` which is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't understand why you need to use `send` at all here. What's wrong with the simple:

```
Hash[@cars.map(&:to_s).zip([0].cycle)]
```

Comment: Simple? Are you sure that someone who writes h["x.to_s"] will be able to understand it?